# How to use shortcode of any plugin to show it visually where i want?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I don't know much about shortcode. I have a countdown plugin with this plugin i'm displaying 'countdown timer', i can post it with shortcode E.g `[countdown event="Event with hour &amp; minutes" date="12 June" hour="18" minutes="54"]`. I tried to fetch it with `get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)` but with this way I can not displaying the 'countdown timer' as visually, just fetch the lettering. Is it possible to show countdown plugin with shortcode where i want. Hope you can help. I really need it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is visual in post, but i want to use this shortcode in (E.g) my category page, i'm going to use it manually. I thought, if i fetch it from post and tried to put it my categorypage.php using `get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)` but it is only displaying as you wrote, just lettering.not visual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID)
```

to

```
echo do_shortcode(get_post_field('post_content', $post->ID));
```

It should work.

Comment: thanks, it works like a charm. clear and working answer thank you again.